# How to find silverlight version using google analytics

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics

I have a website which runs on silverlight. I am using google analytics to measure trends and understand user behaviour and I wonder how do i find (1) if user have silverlight pre-installed (2) if silverlight already installed, what version is that(3) If we made user installed silverlight.

I know that Google Analytics can detect flash version by default, how do i make it detect silverlight version as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if GA will eventually add it in, but until then...

You can grab a helper file called [Silverlight.js](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs) file from microsoft, to be included on your page. The file gives you easy methods for finding out answers to those questions, and then you would pass record that data using [custom variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html)